# Two php scripts in html file.. include a php not displaying

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a simple form to show a basic table and a delete query...
I can get the delete query working but when I use an include it does not work, if i run the 'display.php' file alone in browser it runs perfectly and shows the database...

Can anyone advise what would be best way incorporate the display.php file in this html file? Or explain the issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>



        <div id="content">
            <?php include('display.php')?>

            <div id="sidebar"></div>

            <div id="footer">
                <h5></h5>
            </div>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form action="delete.php" method="post"></form>

                        <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" style="background-color: #536977" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="150">Enter Username to be deleted</td>

                                <td width="6">:</td>

                                <td width="294"><input name="delusername" type="text"></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>

                                <td>&nbsp;</td>

                                <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What extension your html file has? And how are those two related in folder tree?

Comment: Some servers need you to put the file like this: `<?php require_once('./display.php') ?>` if they are in the same dir.

Comment: If your html file has the extension `.html`, your web server will not do any processing so it'll only serve it. It has to have a `.php` extension and then you'd be able to include it.

Comment: Hey, yes i just checked it with the previous posts below, and it was indeed require once, I was using include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php  require_once('display.php'); ?>
```

Presuming they are in the same folder.

Comment: include would have worked too, the difference being that you need this file to carry on so hence the require, if it was an include and failed the script carries on and when that missing script is a DB call it normally renders the rest of the script useless.. I always put the _once in to make sure that the script is not added again, mostly it would cause errors if it tries to redeclare a function. You can use _once after an include aswell.

Comment: I was just trying to display the file that was all so I thought include would work first time.. wasn't sure why. oh also, if I do move the display file back a folder so it's hidden, will it work as normal with require, or any changes.

Comment: just change the path same as an image for instance ( ../inc/classes/display.php ) or whatever should do it providing the script has read write execute permissions on the folder. if you haven't got the perms try changing to chmod of the folder to , I think , 0644

Comment: Thanks Billy, appreciate it